# Display specific power settings profiles

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-management

I have a notebook + external HDMI display. I'm looking for a way to set up power settings profiles.

For example, I want to hibernate notebook if I close it when there is only one display. But I want to do nothing when I close notebook with external display.

Do you have any ideas how I could do it? Maybe there are some ways to set up it using windows settings or some external application.

Comment: [powercfg](http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html) - Control power settings, configure Hibernate/Standby modes. You create multiple power profiles ...

Comment: I have not seen any settings that will enable you to do this with plain Windows 10. Can't you tie it to a different parameter, such as plugged into AC power?